# Laptop needs to be restarted after I close the lid

Tags: screen

I close the lid on my HP Pavilion laptop, and when I open it, I have to restart the laptop because the screen displays random streaks of colors. Is there any way to fix this? I have only used Ubuntu for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to change the behavior of the close-lid function and see if you have the same problem, set it to "blank screen", it's in `screen saver - power management - when laptop lid is closed -> blank screen` and eventually disable the screen saver. By the way I find this setting much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem, too (also HP pavilion, in my case dv7)

for me, it was related to the tv card: going to standby made part of the system forget the card, and waking would often not work due to the kernel constantly trying to reenable the card again.

for me, some kernel update fixed it.

PS: i know this is no real answer, but maybe the problem is similar and i could point you in the right direction